# Selenium python bindings - mouse over action

Tags: python, action

Related to selenium python bindings - mouse over action

This is the code used
Tried this to perform hover action,still not working

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Documents")
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: @Pat:got this error message.ERROR: test_mouseover_browse (__main__.TestMouseoverBrowse)
  hover.perform()

Comment: Can you provide more details on this? like website?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://tomerlerner.com/')
action = ActionChains(browser)
x = action.move_to_element(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/section[2]/ul/li[1]/a'))
x.perform()
```